# NullReferenceException on ASP.NET PreviousPage Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I followed the directions from MSDN on transferring data between asp.net pages.

But when using the 'PreviousPage' property to access the previous pages controls, I get a null ref exception that PreviousPage is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Portal : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return txt_User.Text;
        }
    }
```

And this is the submit button on initial page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" onclick="btn_Submit_Click" 
    PostBackUrl="~/Query.aspx"
```

Previous page property on second page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Username = PreviousPage.Username; 
    }
```

As per MSDN instructions I also added this at the top of the second pages markup file:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Portal.aspx" %>
```

Also note I have tried Server.Transfer to switch pages instead and that produces the same error.

EDIT, here is using Server.Transfer on the initial page click event:

```
 protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Query.aspx"); 
    }
```

EDIT, button code without event handler:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server"
    PostBackUrl="~/Query.aspx"
    style="height: 26px" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: Where have you tried Server.Transfer - can you show the code you used then?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. If PreviousPage is null, that generally indicates the current page was not displayed as a result of a cross-page postback.

Can you confirm the error is being raised on the second page?

Also, what the `onclick="btn_Submit_Click"` in your button definition? There should be no code responding to the click event on the original page. Remember, it will be handled by the target page.

**EDIT:** Now that you've updated your question, my last point seems to be the issue. You are doing a server transfer from the original page. This is **NOT** a cross-page postback and that's why PreviousPage is null.

Remove the onclick attribute from your button and delete btn_Submit_Click.

Comment: I removed the event handler, still the same error. The error comes up on the second pages code-behind file where PreviousPage.Username is accessed.

Comment: Yes see above. Removed the event handler and btn_Submit_Click, just using PostBackUrl.

Comment: That should work, unless you have something else wrong. Step through your Load event in the target page using the debugger. Is it PreviousPage that's null? Also, I'd probably stick a breakpoint in btn_Submit_Click to make absolutely certain it's not still being called from somewhere.

Comment: PreviousPage is null, but I noticed that Page_Load fires twice and its only the 2nd time that comes up null after the value is actually already loaded, is that normal? I have a datagrid on the page and call DataBind() that might refresh the page firing Page_Load again. Might be the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. Change your Load event in the target page to only reference PreviousPage if !IsPostBack. This way, the code won't do anything if it is posting back. Ideally, it should also verify PreviousPage is not null before referencing it.
    {
        Username = PreviousPage.Username; 
    }